# How to hide bootstrap nav bar brand on home page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can you hide bootstrap nav bar brand on the index page only above a width of 768px. This is at the point when the website become responsive and change the menu bar.

[image: This is the desktop view of the home page and I want to hide the Eat Sleep Kayak text in the top left till it hits the brake point for tablets at 768px]

[image: This is the table view.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Class `.hidden-xs` to the navbar-brand

Answer (score 0):

add class .visible-xs

```
Classes Devices 
.visible-xs Extra small (less than 768px) visible 
.visible-sm Small (up to 768 px) visible 
.visible-md Medium (768 px to 991 px) visible 
.visible-lg Larger (992 px and above) visible 
.hidden-xs Extra small (less than 768px) hidden 
.hidden-sm Small (up to 768 px) hidden 
.hidden-md Medium (768 px to 991 px) hidden 
.hidden-lg Larger (992 px and above) hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to set the condition.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-brand {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

or add `hidden-md hidden lg` to `navbar-brand` class in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in index.html or homepage only.

```
<style> 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
 }
}
</style>
```